# ForEach-Object removing lines from a file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am putting together a simple PowerShell script that will find/replace a various number of keywords. If the keywords are found, it should replace them with a different phrase.

This works for lines where the keywords exist, however the script is removing lines where the keywords DO NOT exist; this is not the behavior I want.

My expectations is that it will replace KEYWORDS and leave everything else untouched.

Script:

```
#*=============================================
#* Script Name: SQLFILE_find_and_replace.ps1
#* Created: 12-Jun-2013
#*=============================================
#* Purpose: Intended for SQLFILE scripts
#* generated from a datapump dump file.
#*
#* Will find and replace "Create [Keyword]"
#* with "Create or Replace [Keyword]" within a
#* specified file.
#*=============================================

#Keywords for find/replace to act on; adjust as necessary.
$KEYWORDS = @("PROCEDURE","PACKAGE","FUNCTION","TYPE","SEQUENCE","VIEW","DATABASE LINK","TRIGGER")

# Get-FileName from http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/09/01/hey-scripting-guy-september-1.aspx
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
    Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
} #end function Get-FileName

#Ask user for file
$FILENAMELOC=Get-FileName -initialDirectory "C:\"


Write-Progress -Activity "Loading file" -status "$FILENAMELOC" -percentComplete 0

$file = (Get-Content -Path $FILENAMELOC)
$lines =  ($file | Measure-Object)
$lineprocessed = 0

$file |
    ForEach-Object {
        $lineprocessed = $lineprocessed + 1
        ForEach ($KEYWORD in $KEYWORDS) {
            if ($_.indexof("$KEYWORD") -ge 0) {
                if ($KEYWORD -eq "SEQUENCE" -and $_.indexof("MINVALUE") -ge 0) {
                    $SEQUENCENAME = $_.Substring($_.indexof("$KEYWORD"),$_.indexof("MINVALUE")-$_.indexof("$KEYWORD")-1)
                    $DROP = "DROP "+$SEQUENCENAME +";"
                    $CREATE = "CREATE "+$SEQUENCENAME +";"
                    $SQL = $DROP+"`r`n"+$CREATE
                    $_ -replace "CREATE $KEYWORD", $SQL
                }
                else {
                    $_ -replace "CREATE $KEYWORD", "CREATE OR REPLACE $KEYWORD"
                }
            }
        }
        Write-Progress -Activity "Replacing keywords" -status "Running" -percentComplete ([System.Math]::Round((($lineprocessed / $lines.count)*100),2))
    } |
    Set-Content $FILENAMELOC
```

Test file:

```
This is a test.
CREATE PROCEDURE Blah
CREATE TRIGGER Boblawbla
CREATE FUNCTION
This is another test

Watch me disappear.
```

Result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Blah
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Boblawbla
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
```

This is a Windows 7 box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your culprit:

```
if ($_.indexof("$KEYWORD") -ge 0) {
  if ($KEYWORD -eq "SEQUENCE" -and $_.indexof("MINVALUE") -ge 0) {
    ...
    $_ -replace "CREATE $KEYWORD", $SQL
  } else {
    $_ -replace "CREATE $KEYWORD", "CREATE OR REPLACE $KEYWORD"
  }
}
```

Only the 2 `$_ -replace ...` produce output that the pipe redirects into `Set-Content`. You seem to assume that the `-replace` operator modifies the content in `$_` and that `Write-Host $_` echoes the line into the pipe. Both is not the case. `$_ -replace ...` takes the value from `$_`, replaces matches it finds, and writes the modified string to STDOUT. `Write-Host` writes messages to the console, not to STDOUT.

Add an `else` branch to echo the lines that don't contain any keywords and you should be fine:

```
if ($_.indexof("$KEYWORD") -ge 0) {
  if ($KEYWORD -eq "SEQUENCE" -and $_.indexof("MINVALUE") -ge 0) {
    ...
    $_ -replace "CREATE $KEYWORD", $SQL
  } else {
    $_ -replace "CREATE $KEYWORD", "CREATE OR REPLACE $KEYWORD"
  }
} else {
  $_
}
```

You're making this way too complicated, though. Something like this should suffice (if I parsed your code correctly):

```
(Get-Content $FILENAMELOC) | % {
  $_ -replace 'CREATE SEQUENCE (\S*)', "DROP `$1;`r`nCREATE `$1" `
     -replace 'CREATE (PROCEDURE|PACKAGE|FUNCTION|TYPE|VIEW|DATABASE LINK|TRIGGER)', 'CREATE OR REPLACE $1'
} | Set-Content $FILENAMELOC
```

Comment: Actually, the Write-host was my way of 'debugging', I wasn't thinking that would pipe to Set-Content, but I removed that from above to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: You're very right. However, If I put an else there, while it spits out a result for every line, it does so 8 times (once for each keyword). Do you have a suggestion as to how to fix that? I feel like I am stuck between one of two options - loop through the file 8 times (once for each keyword) or loop through the file once, and loop through each line 8 times. Your explanation was very helpful, I did think that -replace modified $_; critical to know that isnt the case. thanks for that

Comment: You're awesome! thanks for the help. I do tend to overcomplicate things, especially when I do not know the language all that well. Thanks again.